# Saving always first image from scrollview to photo album

Tags: iphone, ios6

Why it is saving only first image from the scrollview to photo album when i select second or any other image all the time it saves only first image from the scrollview to photo album

```
- (void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer{
//CGPoint gesturePoint = [_gesture locationInView:_imageScrollView]; 
if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan){
    UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Save Photo", nil];
    actionSheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent;
    [actionSheet showInView:self.view];
    [actionSheet release];

}}

-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
switch (buttonIndex) {
    case 0:
         for (int i = 0; i<=61; i++) {
             NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%d.png", i];
             UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
             UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
             //if     (CGRectContainsPoint(_myButton.frame,gesturePoint)){  
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(imageView.image, self, @selector(image: didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);

       break;

    default:
        break;
} }}
```

It should save the selected image always.

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with your code.

1. You are creating a `UIImageView` but your are not using it, just the image. There is really no use for this object.
2. You should check if `image0.png`, `image1.png`, `image2.png` really exist. A simple `NSLog` statement will show you. If they are `nil`, it would not be surprising that they are not saved.
3. Nowhere in your code do you reference the selection, you just use a hard-coded number of 62 images. Your `imageNamed` method would be pulling these out of the application bundle, if present.

Comment: some people always tell me everything two times some do it twice i think you should read my answer you should read this answer I wrote